How to transform nested arrays by extending the dimension of the array
Suppose I have an array X with N elements. I would like then to input this array into a 2D array A as follows
X=np.array([0,1,2,3],dtype=np.float64)

A=np.array([[0,0,X],
            [0,X,0]],dtype=np.float64)


If I do this, what I will get is an array inside another array and this would be the output
A=array([[0, 0, array([0, 1, 2, 3])],
       [0, array([0, 1, 2, 3]), 0]], dtype=object)

with shape (3,2) along with a new array type.
I would like something different in the output. I would like to 'extend' the dimension of A in the following way:
A[:,:,0]=array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]], dtype=object)
A[:,:,1]=array([[0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0]], dtype=object)
...


i.e. to create a 3rd vector in A to accommodate the array elements from X.

As a worst case you could convert the numpy array to a list of lists, then use splice assignment to the lists and convert it back to an array.

what would be the expected output? you can't have an array with different lengths within a dimension

@mozway what do you mean? The output I get is the nested arrays I wrote before. However, I would like to get as output a different rearrangement of this A matrix, as I define later on.

that part is unclear, so what is your issue exactly if your code is already doing what you want?

oh I see. The issue is that the code is not doing what I want. It gives me an output for A (a nested array) and what I want is the output defined as A[:,;,N]. Notice what the dimensions of both systems are different.

import numpy as np

X = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=np.float64)
A = np.zeros([X.size, 2, 3], dtype=np.float64)
A[:, 0, 2] = X
A[:, 1, 1] = X
print(A)

gives
[[[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 1.]
  [0. 1. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 2.]
  [0. 2. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 3.]
  [0. 3. 0.]]]

and
import numpy as np

X = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=np.float64)
A = np.zeros([2, 3, X.size], dtype=np.float64)
A[0, 2, :] = X
A[1, 1, :] = X
print(A)

gives
[[[0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 1. 2. 3.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 1. 2. 3.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]]]

If I understand correctly, one of those two is desired result.

If I understand your question correctly, you want a "broadcasted blend" of A and X. What I mean by this is:

Assume A has shape m×n (2D) and X has shape p (1D), then the result (let's call it R) is supposed to have shape m×n×p (3D).
In the result R, the elements of A are supposed to be repeated p times along the last dimension.
In the result R, the elements along the last dimension at given 2D indices ([0, 2] and [1, 1] in the example from your question) should be replaced by the p values of X.

If this interpretation is correct, then I am afraid you cannot directly achieve this by placing X into A, because this will not automatically extend A into the third dimension. However, you can achieve the desired result by (1) manually creating a 3D array of appropriate shape yourself and (2) filling it as desired:
import numpy as np

dtype = np.float64

X = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=dtype)  # 1D, 4 elements
A = np.zeros((2, 3), dtype=dtype)  # 2D, 2×3 elements

# Create result array `R` and fill up manually
R = np.empty(A.shape + X.shape, dtype=dtype)  # 3D, 2×3×4 elements
# Broadcast 2D data from `A` into 3D shape of `R` with `np.newaxis`
R[...] = A[..., np.newaxis]
# Place `X` at desired 2D indices
R[0, 2] = X
R[1, 1] = X

print(R[:, :, 0])
# >>> [[0. 0. 0.]
#      [0. 0. 0.]]
print(R[:, :, 1])
# >>> [[0. 0. 1.]
#      [0. 1. 0.]]

The previous code will work with A containing arbitrary values. Alternatively – assuming A is an all-zeros array, as in the question – you could (1) place 1s in the desired 2D indexes, (2) append a new dimension using np.newaxis, and then (3) multiply with X, to produce the same result with fewer steps:
import numpy as np

dtype = np.float64

X = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=dtype)
A = np.array([[0, 0, 1],
              [0, 1, 0]], dtype=dtype)
R = A[..., np.newaxis] * X

print(R[:, :, 0])
# >>> [[0. 0. 0.]
#      [0. 0. 0.]]
print(R[:, :, 1])
# >>> [[0. 0. 1.]
#      [0. 1. 0.]]

